# weird java behavior with nested closures losing captured variable values

Tags: java, debugging

OK this is going to be a bit long and complex, I'm hoping for some rubber ducking here.
I have this code, which is actually a bit more complex, but I think i did a reasonable job of simplifying it:

```
private Result getResult(Request request, RequestType type) {                                                             
   final String date = request.getData(); // marker 1
   final DataSource jdbcDataSource = getDataSource();
   final JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate = newJdbcOperations(jdbcDataSource);
   final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = createTransactionTemplate(jdbcDataSource);      
   Supplier<Integer> createResult = () -> transactionTemplate.execute(transactionStatus -> {
      List<Map<String, Object>> rs = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM table");
      if (rs.size() > 0) {
         return ((Number) rs.get(0).get("count")).intValue();         
      } else {
         log.info(request + " not found in table");
      }
      if (type == TYPE1) {
         //...
      } else {
         throw new RuntimeException("unexpected type:" + type); // marker2
      }
      return 0;
   });
   int retryCount = 0;
   while (retryCount < 5) {
      try {
         totalCount = createResult.get();            
         break;
      } catch (DuplicateKeyException | DeadlockLoserDataAccessException e) {
         // log
      }
      retryCount++;
   }
}
```

This works fine, except that today the app server got into a state where it stopped working.  The method enters, gets past line "marker1" so we know request is not null, then proceeds to log "null not found in table" suggesting that request turned into null and then throws runtimeException "marker2" because type has turned into null as well.
I hate to say it but this really just smells like a bug in JVM, but this really should be the last to consider, so I'm hoping that you, my dear rubber duck, would have some ideas.

Comment: Do you need to make your `request` final, or does your code compile like that?

Comment: is this reproducible?

Comment: Obviously compiles like that, I wouldn't be having a runtime problem with it, eh?  request is effectively final.  The problem is reproducible in the sense that I have a tomcat running right now which seems to reproduce it 100% of the time, has been like that since 2pm today.  Worked fine for a month before.

Comment: Any change/upgrade to jdk on the server-side? Perhaps it compiles with the jdk on your machine, but the result is toast with the jdk on the server?

Comment: No there haven't been any changes, its one of multiple identically configured JVMs running java 8u71.

Comment: If it is a JDK/JVM bug, it's likely to be in the compilation or execution of the lambda expression. Replace it with a functional interface and see whether it works. I assume your job is to make the program run, not debug the JDK./JVM. See if the same happens with other variable types.

Also, log the value of `request` immediately before the `createResult` assignment and as a first statement in the lambda to verify the suspicion that it's not correctly evaluated in it.

Comment: Yeah, the plan is to make fields explicitly final and add more logging.  I'm assuming some kind of JIT fiasco.   It would be super interesting to figure out what exactly happened, but i don't even know how to begin doing it.

Comment: For a start look at the JVM code with `javap -c`. Ideally you should compare the one that works (from the simplified version) with the one that fails.

Comment: There is no code that works and code that fails. There is code which worked for a month and then stopped, and then after tomcat was restarted it works fine again.